# How to deliver an Excel spreadsheet in XML format to IE10 + Office 2010?

Tags: excel, mime-types, internet-explorer-10, office-2010

I'm trying to deliver an Excel document to the user, which is composed in XML format. The content begins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
etc...
```

I was delivering this as an `.xls` file, MIME type simply `application/excel` and `Content-Disposition: attachment`. In IE < 10 and Office < 2010, it would open directly in MS Excel, no problems.

Now, with IE10 and Office 2010, behaviour is completely different and I can't get it to work. Excel is complaining that the format is different to the file extension (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsDy8.gif). This occurs no matter which of the possible Excel MIME types I use.

If I change the extension to `.xml`, IE keeps trying to open it in a new tab, resulting in nothing but a blank page. Again, this occurs no matter what MIME type I try, and regardless of the "attachment" setting (which is supposed to open it outside IE).

What am I doing wrong here, considering it used to work fine before?

Comment: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/08/11/Excel-Extension-Hardening-and-Web-Applications.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, unfortunately changing group policy for users isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting with the same problem.
I solve it by setting the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` (like you do) and the `ContentType` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`.
I tested with Chrome, IE and Firefox. Only by Firefox, the browser add the .xls extension if I choose "Open with". Otherwise the file was downloaded.
I hope this helps you.